# Why can't I get Nanoc to compile my site on Windows 8?

Tags: ruby, nanoc

I've updated to Windows 8, and my same site used to compile in Windows 7, and still does compile on another Windows 7 machine, but I can't get it working.  This is the output from the console when I attempt to `nanoc compile` things:

```
nanoc compile

Loading site data... done

Captain! We've been hit!

Message:

EOFError: end of file reached

Compilation stack:

  (empty)

Stack trace:

  0. lib/static.rb:41:in `readpartial'
  1. lib/static.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in checksum_for'
  2. lib/static.rb:39:in `open'
  3. lib/static.rb:39:in `block in checksum_for'
  4. lib/static.rb:37:in `map'
  5. lib/static.rb:37:in `checksum_for'
  6. lib/static.rb:21:in `block in items'
  7. lib/static.rb:13:in `map'
  8. lib/static.rb:13:in `items'
  9. C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nanoc-3.5.0/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/
site.rb:310:in `block in load_items'
  ... 35 more lines omitted. See full crash log for details.

If you believe this is a bug in nanoc, please do report it at
-> https://github.com/ddfreyne/nanoc/issues/new <-

A detailed crash log has been written to ./crash.log.
```

Obvious Error message is obvious, but I can't actually figure out how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well the problem seems to have been with the static data source plugin I was using.  I removed the `static.rb` file in my `libs/` folder, it turns out that it's now built in to the latest version of nanoc (3.5.x), so I don't even need it.

Question not answered, but made irrelevant.

Comment: Does the static data source that comes with nanoc 3.5.x crash too?

Comment: No, the one that's bundled works fine, it seems like it was just 3rd party one I was using with 3.4.x was the problem.  Probably nothing to  do with Windows 8 at all! Just nanoc versions!